# Связываем web с сервером cs

Tags: c#, php, c++

Если кто тут знает как это сделать, то подскажите как) Подобной информации в интернете нету) Суть: есть сайт, нужно соединить сайт с сервером игры -- Counter-Strike 1.6, я не понимаю как именно это реализовать, но чуть чуть понимаю что и как, например, понимаю, то что с сайта посылаются определенные команды. Так же не понимаю как берется статистика с сервера, значит есть какой-то язык который парсит в PHP это и т.д. Если кто понимает о чем я то прошу поделитесь :) Так же предоставляю ссылку на сайт, где это все реализовано, примерно как там.

Ссылка: [fastcup.net](http://fastcup.net/)

Ссылка №2: [fragarena.ru](http://fragarena.ru/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для запуска сервера CS вам необходимо запустить на той же машине веб-сервер с php. Далее создаете PHP файл.

Для Windows: `exec('c:/cs_start.exe');` или (если не работает) `shell_exec("c:/cs_start.exe");`
Для Linux: `shell_exec("c:/cs_start.sh");`

Для запуска на стороннем сайте есть такая реализация:

Вы направляете по нажатию на кнопку пользователя на cs-server-ip-addr/start.php
В этом скрипте на самом сервере просто прописываете что то типа:

```
<?php
exec('c:/cs_start.exe');
echo 'Сервер запущен!<br /><a href="#">Назад</a>';
?>
```

Или Вы можете посылать запрос на этот скрипт из другого скрипта через file_get_contents

Comment: Вроде, все понял, но ещё мучает вопрос, нагрузка будет на сам сайт ? 
ведь, если подсчитать около 2000-1000 пользователей в день, из них играю 200-300 (игр) то есть столько серверов запуститься, и ещё: 

параметры к запуску можно указать в функции ? именно от самой игры, например, максимальное количество игроков на сервере, пароль...

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, можете сделать сервер и сайт отдельным. На сайте используйте file_get_contents , насчет параметров не знаю, но с флагами вы можете запустить приложение (exec('c:/cs_start.exe -flag');)

Comment: @misc, все верно, я не правильно сказал, - "параметры" это называется флаги, значит можно. Спасибо огромное, что уделили столь большое время.

Comment: @misc, ещё раз спасибо)) все подробно и понятно :)

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, обновил ответ, теперь Вам наверное будет понятнее :-)

Comment: @misc, попробовал, но ведь сервер cs 1.6 не будет так запускаться) то есть определенным файлом: start.exe, там их нету просто... как тогда быть ?

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, а как он запускается?

Answer (score 2):

для мониторинга существуют уже готовые скрипты, которые используют проток CS и коннектятся, это гуглится. информации и примеров полно.

Comment: @Manitikyl, действительно, зачем изобретать велосипед :)

Comment: я не про мониторинг имею ввиду, там все сложнее, с сайта идет запрос на запуск сервера, мониторинг может такое ?)

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, вы хотите запустить сервер через мониторинг?

Comment: Для того чтобы запускать, с WEB сервер CS, обычно используют такую систему как TELNET.

Comment: там все автоматически, или с помощью TELNET тоже можно это сделать ?

Comment: @misc, мне хоть как, главное чтобы работало)

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, напишите .sh скрипт старта и открываете его через PHP. Пример: shell_exec('/home/scripts/cs.sh'); . Так же можно не писать SH а сразу делать запуск через php. Пример: shell_exec('cd / & ls');. Подробнее тут: http://php.net//manual/ru/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, отредактировал свой ответ, посмотрите